# Get all permutations of a list in python without duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to write a script that gets a set of strings-

```
["ab", "ls", "u"]
```

Then creates every possible combination of them, but doesn't necessarily use all of them. I want possible outputs for the above example to be:

```
ab
ab ls
ab ls u
ab u ls
ab u

ls
ls ab
ls ab u
ls u ab
ls u

u
u ls
u ls ab
u ab ls
u ab
```

My script, having removed the other things it does:

```
stuff = ["ab", "ls", "u"]

for subset in itertools.permutations(stuff):
    concat = ""
    for part in subset:
        concat = concat + part

    #the rest of my script now uses this data
```

It returns:

```
ablsu
abuls
lsabu
lsuab
uabls
ulsab
```

How would I make it return what I want?

Comment: Have a final list as l = [] and then do inside the second for loop `l.append(concat)`.

Comment: "doesn't necessarily use all of them" - Could you expand on this? It seems like it might be important, like if you ultimately don't want certain combinations, it might make more sense to not bother generating them.

Comment: I meant that I wanted ones that weren't the full length of 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combinations and permutations together. This should be able to get you going

```
a = ["ab", "ls", "u"]
for i in range(1, len(a)+1):
    for comb in combinations(a, i):
        for perm in permutations(comb):
            print(perm)
```

Output:

```
('ab',)
('ls',)
('u',)
('ab', 'ls')
('ls', 'ab')
('ab', 'u')
('u', 'ab')
('ls', 'u')
('u', 'ls')
('ab', 'ls', 'u')
('ab', 'u', 'ls')
('ls', 'ab', 'u')
('ls', 'u', 'ab')
('u', 'ab', 'ls')
('u', 'ls', 'ab')
```

You can handle `comb` how ever you see fit

Answer (score 1):

As you are giving list with 3 elements permutations is giving you back result with all 3 elements.
You need to supply 1 element to get your `ab`/`ls`/`u` in output.
You need to supply 2 element to get your `ab ls`/`ab u` in output.

So same program you can use by calling it with 1/2 elements in list.

```
stuff = ["ab", "ls", "u"]

for subset in itertools.permutations(stuff):
    concat = ""
    for part in subset:
        concat = concat + part

    #the rest of my script now uses this data

stuff = ["ab", "ls"]

for subset in itertools.permutations(stuff):
    concat = ""
    for part in subset:
        concat = concat + part


stuff = ["ls", "u"]

for subset in itertools.permutations(stuff):
    concat = ""
    for part in subset:
        concat = concat + part
```

Comment: Don't repeat yourself! I think you can use the `r` parameter of [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to accomplish the same thing. You would just need an outer loop, `for r in range(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff = ["ab", "ls", "u"]
final_list = []
for subset in itertools.permutations(stuff):
    concat = ""
    for part in subset:
        concat = concat + part
        final_list.append(concat)

print(final_list)

['ab',
 'abls',
 'ablsu',
 'ab',
 'abu',
 'abuls',
 'ls',
 'lsab',
 'lsabu',
 'ls',
 'lsu',
 'lsuab',
 'u',
 'uab',
 'uabls',
 'u',
 'uls',
 'ulsab']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

stuff = ["ab", "ls", "u"]

for i in range(len(stuff) + 1):
    for x in itertools.permutations(stuff[:i]):
        print(x)
```

But this solution show all permutations::

```
()
('ab',)
('ab', 'ls')
('ls', 'ab')
('ab', 'ls', 'u')
('ab', 'u', 'ls')
('ls', 'ab', 'u')
('ls', 'u', 'ab')
('u', 'ab', 'ls')
('u', 'ls', 'ab')
```